# How to create a numpy-array from literals using astropy units?

Tags: python, astropy

My method receives scalar values "disguised" as astropy-quantities. I want to make a numpy-array out of them which shall carry the same (base)-unit.

Here is what I did in the first place:

```
from astropy.units import km, m
from astropy.units.quantity import Quantity
import numpy as np

def method(a: Quantity, b: Quantity):
    c = np.array((a, b))

method(3 * km, 2000 * m)
```

This does not work: `TypeError: only dimensionless scalar quantities can be converted to Python scalars`

I changed the method so that it first converts everyone to same unit and then I'm applying this unit.

```
def method(a: Quantity, b: Quantity):
    c = np.array((a.to('km').value, b.to('km').value)) * km
```

It seems boilerplated to me, is there a more elegant way to write this? Something I have overseen in astropy's unit-system?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to have anything else than an homogeneous NumPy array with only one unit with `astropy.units`. You might want to use a Pandas DataFrame and have a different array for each column, with its own unit.
If you're okay with using a different library, take a look at https://pint.readthedocs.io. It will just convert you units to a common one though:

```py
import pint
import numpy as np

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

a = [3, 4] * ureg.meter + [4, 3] * ureg.cm
# <Quantity([ 3.04  4.03], 'meter')>
np.sum(a)
# <Quantity(7.07, 'meter')>
```

Comment: I imagine with pint the same problem exists: `a = np.array([3 * ureg.meter, 4 * ureg.meter])`?

Comment: That's right. One solution is to use an `object` dtype: `a = np.array([3 * ureg.meter, 4 * ureg.meter], dtype='object')`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281486/how-do-i-make-a-numpy-array-from-a-list-of-pint-quantities